# CSS card flip back content is delayed

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I am working a website in which I am using a card flip animation with content on the front and on the back. The animation is done through CSS and is activated when hovered over, which is working fine.

My issue is that I am including an `<a>` tag which is absolutely positioned on the back. The first flip of any card results in a delay before displaying the back-face content. This can be seen [at this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2o16abs0/2/).

I have narrowed the issue down to it being caused by the `position: absolute` property, as when I remove that line, there is no delay, however I want the link to be at the bottom of the card no matter how long or large the description text is. Any idea on how I can avoid this delay? There is no delay after the first flip, and even though it won't ruin the entire site, it isn't ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only position absolute is the problem then remove it and use flex to achieve it.

If you want to learn flex then [flexbox froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) is the fun way to learn it.

I have made same changes in your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79csgwun/) too.

```css
.projectCardWrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.projectCard {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    border-radius: 10%;
}

.projectCard:hover {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    display: flex;
}

.projectName {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.projectLink {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: larger;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="projectCardWrapper cardWrapper">
  <div class="projectCard card">
    <div class="front">
      <p class="projectName">abc</p>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p class="projectDescription">Description</p>
      <a href="test.html" class="projectLink">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh I don't know how I forgot about flex, this worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi sal, if this helped you, don't forget to upvote as well.